# Understanding compact code snippet

Tags: python

I have inherited some Python scripts and I'm working to understand them. I am a beginner-level Python programmer but very experienced in several other scripting languages.

The following Python code snippet generates a file list which is then used in a later code block. I would like to understand exactly how it is doing it.  I understand that `os.path.isfile` is a test for filetype and `os.path.join` combines the arguments in to a filepath string. Could someone help me understand the rest?

```
flist = [file for file in whls if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(whdir, i, file))]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: `things_we_want = [thing for thing in list_of_things if we_want(thing)]`

Comment: @Davidmh that's possibly the most concise means of explanation I've ever seen....

Answer (score 1):

`whls` is an iterable of some kind.

For each element in `whls`, it checks if `os.path.join(whdir, i, that_element)` is a file.
(`os.path.join("C:","users","adsmith")` on Windows is `r"C:\users\adsmith"`)

If so, it includes it in that list.

As @jonsharpe posted in the comments, this is an example of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which are well worth your time to master.

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension means that python will iterate over each member of `whls` (this is maybe a tuple/list?), and for each item, it will test whether `os.path.join(whdir, i, file)` is a file (as opposed to a directory etc). It will return a list containing only the elements from whls that pass this condition check.

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension is equivalent to the following loop:

```
flist = []
for file in whls:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(whdir, i, file)):
        flist.append(file)
```

The list comprehension is more compact. Performance-wise, they are similar, with the list  comprehension being a little faster because it doesn't load the append() method.

Comment: Thank you for the alternate code. It made it much easier to understand. I will work on learning list comprehension.